# When we have a clear context, can we omit words, phrases, clauses, or even sentences?

Tags: usage, idiomatic-language

**My question:**

When we have a clear context, can we omit words, phrases, clauses, or even sentences? Because I think they are sometimes too long or kind of wordy.

Is there a rule of thumb or something in terms of this?

---

**Examples I came up with:**

I came up with these scenarios; I don't know if they are acceptable or not to you guys.

The contents in the parentheses are things I think we can omit.

**Scenario 1**

> A: You played for the varsity basketball team. You must be skilled (at basketball).

> B: Yeah, I am proficient (in playing basketball).

**Scenario 2**

> A: Do you know Estée Lauder? Their products are good.

> B: Yeah, I have an eyeliner (of Estée Lauder) and a lip gloss (of Estée Lauder).

**Scenario 3**

> A: I am going to that breakfast shop.

> B: Ok, you go first and I will catch up. I will probably have a burger and tea (from that shop).

**Scenario 4**

> A: The venue has lots of equipment. We have to know all the devices' locations

> B: Yes, we should be familiar (with their locations).

Comment: 1-3 are fine. 4 is comprehensible, but I don't think a native speaker would say it - we might say "Yes, we should", or "Yes we should be familiar with them", but _familiar_ tends not to be used without an object in that sense. More generally, Look up [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) for a discussion of this phenomenon, which is not restricted to English.

Comment: @ColinFine I believe this phenomenon appears when the information such as the topic or the scope of the discourse is clear. But it is kind of hard for non-native speakers like me, because we don't know how to omit or reduce our sentences. Sometimes we make long, wordy sentences as a result. And finally, I remember the phenomenon is called the economy principle in language?